# What does a sound wave's frequency content tell us about the motion of particles in the wave?

Tags: waves, acoustics, fourier-transform

The Fourier of a quasi-periodic pressure wave traveling through air gives that wave's frequency content. And it should be harmonic (right?).

If it has 5dB of 440Hz, what does that tell me about the air particles in the original wave?

Can I infer anything about particle motion from the frequency content?

Comment: Something that might help is to remember that the 5dB in your example is a relative measurement.  Decibels measure the relative magnitude of values.  If you can figure out what you are measuring relative to, that's a big hint as to the motion.  (e.g. if I speak of a 70dB soundwave, it is *typically* with respect to I0, the pressure of the wave at the edge of human hearing)

Comment: Cort Ammon is right. You have to acquire some info about the measurement (a reference value will be "hidden" somewhere in there) in order to perform calibration. Otherwise you won't be able to infer anything about absolute values, since the deciBel scale is a relative scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**: For simple waves (described below), the maximum particle velocity is independent of the frequency and depends only on the pressure amplitude.  The maximum particle displacement does depend on the frequency.  However, these simple waves are very limiting, so a deeper analysis is probably needed for any particular situation.  (It is possible that these features are not specifically what was desired, but "the motion of the particles" is rather vague, so this is what I decided to focus on.)

**Longer Answer**:

For a progressive wave (the wave passes you and there is no echo) made of only one frequency you may write the pressure $p$ as
$$p=A\cos\left[2\pi f(t-x/c)+\phi\right],$$
where $A$ is the amplitude, $f$ is the frequency, $t$ is time, $x$ is position, $c$ is the wave speed, and $\phi$ is some phase constant.  The level (the "decibels") is then given by
$$L=20\log_{10}\frac{A}{p_0},$$
where $p_0$ is some reference pressure (in air this is 20 $\mu$Pa).  Finally, we obtain from conservation of momentum
$$\rho\ddot u = \frac{2\pi f}{c}A\sin\left[2\pi f(t-x/c)+\phi\right],$$
where $\rho$ is the air density, $u$ is the particle displacement (how far it has moved from its rest position), and the dots denote time derivatives.  You can easily integrate in time once to obtain
$$\dot u = \frac{A}{\rho c}\cos\left[2\pi f(t-x/c)+\phi\right] = \frac{p}{\rho c}.$$

Combining all of these together, the maximum particle velocity at a given level is
$$\dot u_\text{max} = \frac{p_0 10^{L/20}}{\rho c},$$
which may be written for air in standard conditions as
$$\dot u_\text{max} \approx 4.82\times10^{(L/20)-8} ~~~(\text{m/s}).$$
If you want the maximum displacement, you take the maximum velocity and (effectively integrating in time again) multiply by $2\pi f$.

If you are interested in standing waves, waves propagating in many directions, or some combination of these, all of these calculations become much more complicated.  You would need to provide a specific situation for analysis.

Comment: You could improve the short answer by stating that you are talking about the _maximum_ velocity and _maximum_ displacement. But note that that might not be what the OP asked about.

Comment: @fishinear Good idea!  I have updated my answer.